# Error Id: VertexFailedFast, Error Message: Vertex failed with a fail-fast error

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory, u-sql

when I run the Below U SQL I am getting "Activity U-SQL1 failed:

> Error Id: VertexFailedFast, Error Message: Vertex failed with a
>   fail-fast error."

The input schema has 7 columns. But still i am getting this error.I'm also skipping the first row because it contains headers.

```
DECLARE @file_set_path string ="/Sample_{*}.csv";
@searchlog =  
       EXTRACT cola string,
            colb string,
            colc string,
            cold string,
            cole string,
            colf string,
            colg string
       FROM  @file_set_path 
       USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);


OUTPUT @searchlog 
      TO  "output.csv" 
      USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Comment: from this path i can see that your file is in root folder on ADL?

Comment: No it is just a sample path. The file is inside a subfolder.

Comment: oh ok. so try with silent: true parameter in Extractor.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. COuld it be because of NULL columns.?

Comment: no. string values can be null.

Comment: can you provide your u sql script?

Comment: I found the issue. It is working now. It was an issue with the way the filename was passed.